# Return ACF field as a Shortcode using Wordpress Functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

How do I use an Advanced Custom Field as a Shortcode. Ive used the following code in the Wordpress functions.php file but no luck.

Here is my Code:

```
function location_date_func( $atts ){

    return "<?php the_field('location_date', 658); ?>";
}
add_shortcode( 'location_date', 'location_date_func' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the shortcode properly, and make it return the data to display, not return a string with php code in it:

```
function location_date_func( $atts ){
    //return string, dont echo it, so use get_field, not the_field
    return get_field('location_date', 658);
}
//create function to register shortcode
function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode( 'location_date', 'location_date_func' );
}
// hook register function into wordpress init
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

Or if you are using php 5.3+, you can use anonomous functions to acheive the same result:

```
add_action('init', function(){
    add_shortcode('location_date', function(){
        return get_field('location_date', 658);
    });
});
```

Comment: @johnnyr209 how exactly are you trying to use this shortcode? The built in shortcode doublesharp provided should work fine, as should this

Comment: The built in shortcode only works on ACF fields it does NOT work on default Wordpress fields.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work!

```
function location_date_func( $atts ){
    return apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field( 'location_details', 658 ) );
        }
add_shortcode( 'location_date_sc', 'location_date_func' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the value of an ACF field using [`the_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_field/), there is already a [built in shortcode](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/shortcode/) to do that.

```
[acf field="location_date" post_id="658"]
```

If you would like to reproduce it using the `[location_date]` shortcode, you need to use [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/) to return rather than echo the value. Syntax-wise, the only problem with your code is that you do not need the double quotes or `<?php` tags, since it should already be inside a PHP block. It will be functionally the same as the `[acf]` shortcode, but does not accept the `post_id` argument. This example will be hard coded to post ID 658 unless you modify it to accept an ID as part of the `$atts` or use the `global $post`;

```
function location_date_func( $atts ){
    return get_field( 'location_date', 658 );
}
add_shortcode( 'location_date', 'location_date_func' );
```

Comment: The default ACF shortcode only works within ACF fields it does not work on any default Wordpress fields. The function code provided does not work. Im thinking it may have to do something with the ACF Post ID

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the issue then - if you want to use regular WordPress custom fields then it has nothing to do with ACF. You need to use the standard `get_post_meta( post_id, 'meta_key', single )`

Comment: you loose the WYSIWYG editor if you use the WordPress custom fields

Comment: I don't think you are asking the right question then... all this does is get the values, if you want to use the ACF fields on the front end that is something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_shortcode('location_start_your_application_group', 'start_your_application_group');

function start_your_application_group() {
    $start_your_application_group = '';
    $start_your_application_group .= '<section class="start-your-application">';
     if ( have_rows( 'start_your_application_group', 'option' ) ) : 
         while ( have_rows( 'start_your_application_group', 'option' ) ) : the_row(); 
           $heading = get_sub_field( 'heading' );
             $content = get_sub_field( 'content' );

             if ( $heading !== '' ) {
                    $start_your_application_group .= '<h3 class="start-your-application__heading">' . $heading . '</h3>';
             }
             if ( $content !== '' ) {
                $start_your_application_group .= '<div class="start-your-application__content">' . $content . '</div>';
             }

             $image = get_sub_field( 'image' );
             if ( $image ) { 
                $start_your_application_group .= '<div class="start-your-application__image-container"><img class="start-your-application__image" src="' . $image['url'] .'" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" /></div>';
            } 
        endwhile;
    endif;
    $start_your_application_group .= '</section>';

    return $start_your_application_group;
}
```